# How to evaluate the MSE of linear regression with noise in every dimension

Tags: statistics, least-squares, linear-regression

I am considering a linear regression problem but with some slight different from that usually discussed.
Suppose there are $m$ distinct points $\boldsymbol{x}_i\in R^n, i = 1, \cdots, m$, lying on the same hyperplane $\{\boldsymbol{y}\in R^{n}: \boldsymbol{p}^{T}\boldsymbol{y} = \alpha\}$, and thus $\boldsymbol{X} = [x_1, \cdots, x_m]\in R^{n\times m}$ satisfies $\boldsymbol{X}^{T}\boldsymbol{p} = \alpha\boldsymbol{1}_{m}$.
Clearly, as long as $m\ge n$, I can solve $\boldsymbol{p}$ and $\alpha$ with least square estimation.

Now I can get access to a noised version of $\boldsymbol{X}$, i.e. $\boldsymbol{Y} = \boldsymbol{X} + \boldsymbol{Z}$ is observed, with $z_{ij}\sim\mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{0}, \sigma^2)$ independent to each other.
Assuming $\alpha = 1$, the least square estimation can be formulated as
$$\min_{\boldsymbol{p}}\|\boldsymbol{Y}^{T}\boldsymbol{p} - \boldsymbol{1}_m\|_2^2$$
Then $\hat{\boldsymbol{p}} = (\boldsymbol{Y}\boldsymbol{Y}^{T})^{-1}\boldsymbol{Y}\boldsymbol{1}_m$.
Obviously, the MSE of this estimation is given by taking the expectation of $\boldsymbol{Z}$:
$$MSE = \mathbb{E}\left[\|\boldsymbol{Y}^{T}(\boldsymbol{Y}\boldsymbol{Y}^{T})^{-1}\boldsymbol{Y}\boldsymbol{1}_m - \boldsymbol{1}_m\|_2^2\right]$$
So here comes the problem: $\boldsymbol{Y}$ is a random variable completely dependent on $\boldsymbol{Z}$, so how can I get rid of it with an inverse $(\boldsymbol{Y}\boldsymbol{Y}^{T})^{-1}$?

I have read through quite some discussions on linear regression and it seems that such situation is hardly considered.
Normally, the linear regression model gives $\boldsymbol{y} = \boldsymbol{W}\boldsymbol{\beta} + \boldsymbol{z}$ with $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}} = (\boldsymbol{W}^{T}\boldsymbol{W})^{-1}\boldsymbol{W}^{T}\boldsymbol{y}$, and the analysis of MSE goes quite naturally as $\boldsymbol{W}$ is fixed and the only randomness comes from $\boldsymbol{y}$.
Then the MSE can be figured out without evaluating the inverse matrix.
Examples of such model can be found in [MSE of Ridge estimator, Linear Regression.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4164931/mse-of-ridge-estimator-linear-regression) or [Optimality of the MSE in gaussian linear regression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2601610/optimality-of-the-mse-in-gaussian-linear-regression).
Actually, such model can be formulated as
$$ \left[\boldsymbol{W}, \boldsymbol{y}\right]\left[
    \begin{array}{c}
        \boldsymbol{\beta} \\
        -1
    \end{array}
\right] = \boldsymbol{z} $$
So the difference between this model and my problem is the noise term.
In the normally discussed model, the noise is only added to the output value $\boldsymbol{y}$.
But in my problem, the noise exists for every dimension of the observed points, which yields a noised inverse matrix that I do not know how to handle.

I am wondering whether such problem has been discussed somewhere or any insights about the noised inverse matrix.
Alternatively, any suggestions on solving the MSE are also appreciated.

Comment: When $m \neq n$, $X + Z$ doesn't make sense ($X$ isn't square)... The model you are thinking of may have some similarities to [mixed models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_model), so maybe reading about those could give you some ideas?

Comment: Actually, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors-in-variables_models) might be closer to what you want...

Comment: Thank you! I think Deming regression is just what I want to consider.